# Spring cloud config server - bootstrap properties file - configuring multiple git repositories

Tags: gitlab, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, configserver, spring-cloud-config-server

I am trying to configure multiple gitlab repositories in my spring cloud config server

i use bootstrap.properties for my spring configuration

The below is my bootstrap.properties file

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.keyAlias=abc.com
server.ssl.key-store=/opt/jboss/security/abc.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=abcd

config.server.configuration.dir=/opt/jboss/config/spring_config

config.server.user.name=user
config.server.user.password=password

spring.cloud.config.server.git.skip.ssl.validation=false
spring.cloud.config.server.git.user.name=username
spring.cloud.config.server.git.user.password=password
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://gitlab1.repo.com/testapi/config-files1.git
```

After looking into this documentation  https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html

I tried to configure another repo like the below

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri.repos.repotwo.pattern=repotwo
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri.repos.repotwo.uri=https://gitlab1.repo.com/testapi/config-files2.git
```

and tried accessing the files with the url like

https://my.configserver.com:8443/repotwo/testfile/master

But it didn't work. most of the articles that i referred to were using .yml files instead of bootstrap.properties. can someone help me on this?